# How to get the Spinner value to save in a variable

Tags: android, android-studio, android-spinner

I know there are several questions around this, but do not quite get how to solve it.
The problem is that I am showing some values from local SQlite database, the different options are shown ok and I can select them and the value displayed is ok. the problem is that when I try to save it, the getSelectedItem, gets the first item on the list. Any help or suggestions on how to solve it would be great.

```
        Product product = new Product();
        productsList = product.getProducts();

        Spinner spinnerProduct = findViewById(R.id.spinnerProduct);

        String[] arrayProduct = new String[productsList.size()];
        for(int i = 0; i < productsList.size(); i++) {
            arrayProduct[i] = productsList.get(i).nameProduct;
        }

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapterProduct = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, arrayProduct);
        adapterProduct.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinnerProduct.setAdapter(adapterProduct);
        spinnerProduct.setOnItemSelectedListener(onItemSelectedListener1);

        String productSelected=spinnerProduct.getSelectedItem().toString();

AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener onItemSelectedListener1 =
        new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener(){
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                       int position, long id) {
                Product product = new Product();
                productsList = product.getProducts();
                int[] arrayProduct = new int[productsList.size()];
                for(int i = 0; i < productsList.size(); i++) {
                    arrayProduct[i] = productsList.get(i).stockCurrent;
                }
                String productStock = String.valueOf(arrayProduct[position]);
                product_amount_available.setText(productStock);
            }
            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {}
        };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to implement `OnItemSelectedListener` and override

```
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
        int pos, long id) {
    // An item was selected. You can retrieve the selected item using
    // parent.getItemAtPosition(pos)
}

public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
    // Another interface callback
}
```

More info can be found here https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/spinner#SelectListener

Comment: thanks for the reply. I did implement it, I just forget to paste it here. I use it to set the value of anothe textview. But do not know how quite to get it right

Comment: Not sure how can this work, since you are creating `onItemSelectedListener1` after you set it to spinner.

Answer (score 1):

A spinner uses Event listening so you cannot just do below in a linear fashion:

```
spinnerProduct.setOnItemSelectedListener(onItemSelectedListener1);

String productSelected=spinnerProduct.getSelectedItem().toString();
```

Basically what your code is doing is setting the listener, and immediately after, it's getting some arbitrary/default value from your spinnerProduct object. But you haven't even entered any input to the spinner yet. You must process all the UI and business logic in the event listener's `onItemSelected()` method only.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I understand what you are saying, but do not know how to implement. Feel free to modify the code, please

Comment: It depends with what you are trying to do with the String value `productSelected`. If you just want to update the UI, you are already doing it in the `onItemSelected` method. And you can always retrieve the selected value from the TextView object outside of the event listener method

Comment: I need to pass the value selected to a method, I have two spinners, so I must get the values. The do not depend on eachother

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help. I solved it. I made the global variables.

```
int idProduct,idStorage;
String productSelected,storageSelected;
```

first fill the spinners

```
Product product = new Product();
        productsList = product.getProducts();
        Storage storage = new Storage();
        storageList = storage.getStorage();

        Spinner spinnerProduct = findViewById(R.id.spinnerProduct);
        spinnerProduct.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

        Spinner spinnerStorage = findViewById(R.id.spinnerStorage);
        spinnerStorage.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

        String[] arrayProduct = new String[productsList.size()];
        for(int i = 0; i < productsList.size(); i++) {
            arrayProduct[i] = productsList.get(i).nameProduct;
        }
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapterProduct = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, arrayProduct);
        adapterProduct.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinnerProduct.setAdapter(adapterProduct);
        spinnerProduct.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

        String[] arrayStorage = new String[storageList.size()];
        for(int i = 0; i < storageList.size(); i++) {
            arrayStorage[i] = storageList.get(i).nameStorage;
        }
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapterStorage = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,  arrayStorage);
        adapterStorage.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinnerStorage.setAdapter(adapterStorage);
        spinnerProduct.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
```

then, as suggested implemented the onclicklisteners

```
@Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int pos, long l) {

        if(adapterView.getId() == R.id.spinnerProduct)
        {
            idProduct=(int) adapterView.getSelectedItemId();
            productSelected=adapterView.getSelectedItem().toString();

            Product product = new Product();
            productsList = product.getProducts();
            int[] arrayProduct = new int[productsList.size()];
            for(int i = 0; i < productsList.size(); i++) {
                arrayProduct[i] = productsList.get(i).stockCurrent;
            }
            String productStock = String.valueOf(arrayProduct[pos]);
            product_amount_available.setText(productStock);

        }
        else if(adapterView.getId() == R.id.spinnerStorage)
        {
            storageSelected=adapterView.getSelectedItem().toString();
            idStorage=(int) adapterView.getSelectedItemId();
        }

    }


    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

    }
```

and at last I passed the values into the method triggered by a button

```
btnSaveTransferProduct.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                        saveTransferProduct(idProduct,productSelected, idStorage, storageSelected);
                }
            }
        });
```